# .NET MAUI Change color of Picker items based on condition

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Can you change the color of specific item of a Picker?

I currently have a Picker that is a list of decimals. I want some values to have the color red if the value is above or under a certain number. And the values in between to have the default color.

Is that possible or should I use a CollectionView instead?

Comment: As you can see in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker), default picker don't support this, but you can try to make an [effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/effects) or a [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers) to archive your goal

Comment: @FabriBertani Custom renderers are the old Xamarin.Forms way of doing this, .NET MAUI offers much easier ways now, e.g. using [handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize).

Comment: If I may ask, what platform is it you want this for?

Comment: @PeterWessberg iOS and Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I have a solution. It is a lot of code so I have started a [Repo](https://github.com/PeterWessberg/MAUISamples) for the complete solution.

What you need is to customize the picker control. For that we use an [handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/).

What we need to do is to take control over the View that display the picker items. It is different for each platform. In iOS we use delegate to get to the picker view.

```cs
private class UIPickerViewDelegateEx : UIPickerViewDelegate
{
    private readonly IPicker _picker;
    private readonly UIColor[] colors;

    public UIPickerViewDelegateEx(IPicker picker)
    {
        _picker = picker;
        colors = new UIColor[]
        {
            UIColor.Green,
            UIColor.Purple,
            UIColor.Blue,
            UIColor.Yellow,
            UIColor.Magenta
        };
    }

    public override UIView GetView(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component, UIView view)
    {
        var colorIndex = row % 5;
        var color = colors[colorIndex];

        UILabel label = new UILabel
        {
            Text = _picker.GetItem((int)row),
            TextColor = color,
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center
        };

        DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
        {
            if (pickerView.ViewFor(row, component) is UILabel updatedLabel)
            {
                updatedLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
                updatedLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
                updatedLabel.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(label.Font.PointSize);
            }
        });

        return label;
    }

    public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        _picker.SelectedIndex = (int)row;
    }
}
```

In Android the MAUI team has used `AppCompatAlertDialog`, not a spinner, for the view. They have made it inaccessable so I 'borrowed' the code and added an adapter for controlling the picker items.

```cs
 private class ArrayAdapterEx : ArrayAdapter<string>
 {
     private readonly IPicker virtualView;
     private readonly Android.Graphics.Color[] colors;

     public ArrayAdapterEx(Context context, int textViewResourceId, string[] objects, IPicker virtualView) : base(context, textViewResourceId, objects)
     {
         this.virtualView = virtualView;
         colors = new Android.Graphics.Color[]
         {
             Android.Graphics.Color.Green,
             Android.Graphics.Color.Purple,
             Android.Graphics.Color.Blue,
             Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow,
             Android.Graphics.Color.Magenta
         };
     }

     public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
     {
         View view = base.GetView(position, convertView, parent);
         TextView textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);

         var colorIndex = position % 5;
         var color = colors[colorIndex];

         var item = GetItem(position); // Exampel of how to get current item
         if (position == virtualView.SelectedIndex)
         {
             textView.SetTextColor(Colors.Red.ToPlatform());
             textView.SetBackgroundColor(Colors.LightGray.ToPlatform());
             textView.Typeface = Typeface.DefaultBold;
         }
         else
         {
             textView.SetTextColor(color);
             textView.SetBackgroundColor(Colors.White.ToPlatform());
         }

         textView.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center;

         return view;
     }
 }
```

Take a look at the [Repo](https://github.com/PeterWessberg/MAUISamples) and see if this is what you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks Peter!

Comment: You’re welcome. If you find it useful please upvote so that other people with the same need can find it more easily.